# Blender 2.9 Basic Extrude Issue

Tags: extrude

Blender 2.9 official
Ubuntu
Basic scene - default cube - no transforms, global orientation
Edit - face select
Select face normal to Y axis - press e to extrude - working as I would expect.
However, if I select the face, then press E, then Y to extrude along the y axis, it goes in Z direction.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Short video of the issue at the link below:

[Extrude Issue in action](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wtch6QWmMvKUFzrDvyZY8MztMOB2Q_L_/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a basic change in behavior - now, when you want to extrude along a global axis you would need to press E for extrude, then Y twice.  Or open the on screen widget and change it from normal to global.

[image]

See the post on Blenderartists:

[BA Thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/2-9-basic-extrude-issue/1253013/5)

Comment: Oh, you're right :). Extrude tool works with normal orientation by default (i believe it always did).

Comment: the weird thing is that if you press E then X it will extrude along the X axis of the normal, right? But if you press E then Z it won't extrude along the Z of the normal (which is the natural normal direction), but this time it will extrude along the global Z axis, and to come back to the normal orientation you need to press Z twice again...